# Functions whose Laplace transforms have prescribed behavior at minus infinity

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics, laplace-transform, limit-theorems

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a non-negative function with entire Laplace transform $\hat{f}$ (in particular $\lim_{t\to \infty}e^{st}f(t)=0$ for all $s$), and $p_0$ a positive integer. Under what conditions on the behavior of $f(t)$ for $t\to +\infty$ will the following conditions hold?

1. $\lim_{s\rightarrow-\infty }\frac{d^p}{ds^p}\ln \hat{f}(s)=0$ for all $p\geq p_0$
2. $\lim_{s\rightarrow-\infty }\frac{d^p}{ds^p}\ln \hat{f}(s)=0$ uniformly in $p\geq p_0$

More generally, how can one relate the behavior of a function $f$ in the neighborhood of $+\infty$ and that of its Laplace transform $\hat{f}$ in the neighborhood of $-\infty$? This question arises in the context of probabilistic limit theorems (analogous to the Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko theorem).